# homepage made for iPhone - size

Tags: iphone, size

I'm trying to make a homepage I'm creating look good on the iphone. But even though the content on the page is only 320px in width, the page is still zoomed far out in the iphone browser. What must you do for safari to display the page in its "real" size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tough to say exactly what you need to do without seeing the page, but all the weird little meta tags that Mobile Safari supports to address these sorts of issues are documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

and here

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/appleapplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html